# Image not uploading to web server

Tags: php, html

I am having some difficulty uploading an image to a folder on my web server. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="upload">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
        $size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
        $temp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $error = $_FILES["image"]["error"];
        $target_file = "/profiles/images/$name";
        move_uploaded_file($temp, $target_file);
    }
?>
```

I've tried echoing out the file name ($name), but it doesn't return anything at all. It's blank for some reason. This is when I try to upload an image. When I echo $target_file, I get this "/profiles/images/", the $name part is not included for some reason.

Comment: You probably want the `$target_file` to be somewhere in your project root?At the moment you're trying to put them in the root of your filesystem where I doubt you have a `/profiles/images` directory?

Comment: I'm trying to put them in example.com/profiles/images

Comment: Where is this PHP file in relation to that directory?

Comment: @JonStirling The PHP file is located example.com/profiles/settings.php

Comment: So `$target_file` should probably be `__DIR__."/images/$name"` or similar.

Comment: @JonStirling It worked! Thanks a lot, but why was the name returning blank when I echo'd it?

Comment: Not sure, can you be more specific about what you echo'd and where?

Comment: @JonStirling I replaced $name, with echo $_FILES["image"]["name"]; it returned a blank

Comment: @user2896120 what is the $_POST["upload"] in your code? I don't see any such field in your form - so the if condition is never executed. Please verify.

Comment: If it is empty (I'm still not sure where you're talking about), then I'd expect that the upload had failed. You should check that there wasn't an error on upload by checking `$_FILES["image"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

Comment: @JonStirling my bad.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check your max upload file size. If in the settings the size is smaller than the file you are trying to upload, nothing is send.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens in those cases when we try to upload very heavy size image, Please try to check your maximum file size, and please for testing try to upload maximum 100kb size of pic through this code. Hope this will work.